# Using external JS-Library (basic primitives diagrams) in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm taking the first steps to migrate a rather large project from javascript to typescript. Beeing a Java developer who started javascript development just about 2 years ago, my toolchain is still rudimentary.

I'm trying to migrate a small JS file to TS as a proof of concept. The JS code configures a [Basic Primitives Diagram](https://www.basicprimitives.com/).

Almost everything did work out. But I'm having big issues declaring the global scoped functions in a way typescript can understand. Here is a small portion of my code:

```
export {}
declare global {
  export interface Window {
    MyGlobalVar: any;
  }

  export ChartItemConfig{
    //properties
  }

  //I thought this and the following declarations would solve the problem. They dont :(
  export interface primitives {
    orgdiagram: Orgdiagram;
  }

  export interface Orgdiagram {
    Config: Config;
  }

  export interface Config {
    //properties
  }
}

window.MyGlobalVar.myGlobalFunction = function (id: string, items: Array<ChartItemConfig>) {
    //... more code
    // @ts-ignore
    let options: Config = new primitives.orgdiagram.Config();
    //... more code
 }
```

I want to get rid of the `@ts-ignore` Statement. But whatever I try, my code wont transpile. I get the error `TS2693: 'primitives' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.`

I'm sure it's a beginners problem, but I can't find the solution in the www.

*Edit:*

It seems i was not clear enough about my problem: `new primitives.orgdiagram.Config();` is valid JS-Code at runtime. How can I declare the symbol in a way TS will understand it is a constructor call?

*Edit:*

Mycurrent version:

```
export {}
declare global {
  export interface Window {
    MyGlobalVar: any;
  }

  export const primitives:Primitives;

  export class Primitives {
    orgdiagram: Orgdiagram;
  }

  export class Orgdiagram {
    Config: () => Config;
  }

  export class Config { }
  
  //... more
}

window.MyGlobalVar.myGlobalFunction  = function (id: string, items: Array<ChartItemConfig>) {
  //The following line fails with: TS7009: 'new' expression, whose target lacks a construct signature, implicitly has an 'any' type
  let options: Config = new primitives.orgdiagram.Config();
  //... more
}
```

*Edit:*

I finally got it to work. The [fettblog.eu introduced me to the constructor interface pattern](https://fettblog.eu/typescript-interface-constructor-pattern), which solved my Problem :)

My working declaration is now

```
export {}
declare global {
      
  const primitives:Primitives;

  class Primitives {
    orgdiagram: Orgdiagram;
  }

  class Orgdiagram {
    Config: ConfigConstructor;
  }

  interface ConfigConstructor{
    new (): Config;
  }

  class Config {
    //....
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood what interfaces are for, they are equal to types/classes, but rather than instantiating them you can make an object that has to fit the properties of the interface a.k.a. `export interface Person { name: string } const myPerson: Person = { name 'Mike' } `

Comment: The interface itself does not exist at runtime, it's only there for the ts-compiler.

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is declare a `const`:

```
declare global {
    export const primitives: Primitives

    export interface Primitives {
        orgdiagram: Orgdiagram;
    }
}
```

In this way you are telling Typescript "trust me, there is a constant declared somewhere else in the global scope that is called `primitives` and whose type is `Primitives`". And it generates the correct code.

As for the constructor, you need to specify that the function is a constructor in order to be able to use it with `new`:

```
export class Orgdiagram {
    Config: { new(): Config };
}
```

Comment: Oh thanks, huge step in the right direction. But there is still the problem TS does not know how to deal with the constructor. Current code:

      `export const primitives:Primitives;`

     `export class Primitives { orgdiagram: Orgdiagram; }`

      `export class Orgdiagram { Config: () => Config;}`

      `export class Config {}`

Current error:

`TS7009: 'new' expression, whose target lacks a construct signature, implicitly has an 'any' type.`

_sorry for the mess with the formatting_

Comment: @samjaf Sorry didn't see you needed that too. You managed to fixed it on your own anyway